# How to test a rate limiting algorithm?

Tags: python, pytest

This is the sliding window rate limiting algorithm I got from [this page](https://dev.to/satrobit/rate-limiting-using-the-sliding-window-algorithm-5fjn):

```
from time import time, sleep

class SlidingWindow:

    def __init__(self, capacity, time_unit, forward_callback, drop_callback):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.time_unit = time_unit
        self.forward_callback = forward_callback
        self.drop_callback = drop_callback

        self.cur_time = time()
        self.pre_count = capacity
        self.cur_count = 0

    def handle(self, packet):

        if (time() - self.cur_time) > self.time_unit:
            self.cur_time = time()
            self.pre_count = self.cur_count
            self.cur_count = 0

        ec = (self.pre_count * (self.time_unit - (time() - self.cur_time)) / self.time_unit) + self.cur_count

        if (ec > self.capacity):
            return self.drop_callback(packet)

        self.cur_count += 1
        return self.forward_callback(packet)


def forward(packet):
    print("Packet Forwarded: " + str(packet))


def drop(packet):
    print("Packet Dropped: " + str(packet))


throttle = SlidingWindow(5, 1, forward, drop)

packet = 0

while True:
    sleep(0.1)
    throttle.handle(packet)
    packet += 1
```

How can I test this time sensitive algorithm in pytest? I want to test `forward_callback` is getting called when the request (by calling `handle()`) passes, and `drop_callback` is getting called when the request fails. How could I simulate a loop in pytest?

Answer (score 0):

You should test the `SlidingWindow` class directly, without testing the loop in the end. The reason is that the `SlidingWindow` is independent and it should work regardless of how it's used.

Since the class is heavily dependent on the current time, you can use [pytest-freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-freezegun/) to simulate the time of the requests.

A test example would be something similar to:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call

from sliding_window import SlidingWindow


def test_handle_overflow(freezer):
    freezer.move_to('2012-01-14 12:00:01')
    forward, drop = MagicMock(), MagicMock()
    throttle = SlidingWindow(5, 1, forward, drop)  # 5 per second -> every 200ms

    # first two should be accepted, while the 3rd should be dropped
    throttle.handle(0)
    freezer.tick(timedelta(milliseconds=200))
    throttle.handle(1)
    freezer.tick(timedelta(milliseconds=50))
    throttle.handle(2)

    forward.assert_has_calls(calls=[call(0), call(1)])
    drop.assert_called_once_with(2)
```